# I need help using multiple content types in a wiki page library

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, content-type, wiki-pages

I currently trying to used multiple custom content types based off of the wiki page content type in one wiki page library. 
"Allow management of content types" has been enabled with the designer

The way I would like this library to work is:

1. Click the "Files" tab in the ribbon
2. Click the "New Document" drop down menu
3. Select one of the content types (Client, Contact, Project)
4. SharePoint Will Ask for the Page Name and content type fields
5. Click create
6. Then it will take you to the new created page.

This issue I'm currently having is when i click on one of the options (Client, Contact, Project) it will ask for a page name then you have to check it in to get to the edit form. The edit form it then loads is the default content type and not the selected content type.

So my questions are.

Is there any way I can combine the page name and edit steps together into one step?

How can I get the edit form to pull from the selected content type?

Thanks in advanced

James T.F

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I maybe wrong completely, please correct me if i am.

The whole purpose of a custom Content Type is that you have different schema or "column" etc per each content type. In order to show these different columns you'll need to have a separate  page layout per each content type. This way when you create a new "Client" it'll show a "Client" page layout with "Client" content type attached to it.

Something like this:
http://www.dotnetcurry.com/showarticle.aspx?ID=638

Comment: We ended up going to an enterprise wiki to do what we needed, but I do appreciate the link it's helping do what we need for the enterprise wiki.